# subprocess.Popen + Win command (dxdiag)

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm studying subprocess right now, after reading the doc, I tried to launch dxdiag but somehow it's not working and I can't figure out why because I don't have any error message.

```
import os
import subprocess


subprocess.Popen("dxdiag -t C:\Users\BLABLA\Desktop\testDiag.txt")
```

Pretty straight forward I though but no text file are generated.
Any hint would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the program and parameters as a list, as shown below:

```
import os
import subprocess


subprocess.Popen(["dxdiag",  "-t",  "C:\Users\BLABLA\Desktop\testDiag.txt"])
```

Comment: Thank you ! Seems to work, however it doesn't take the folder as is. I guess I would it to put it into a variable.

    subprocess.Popen(["dxdiag",  "-t",  "testDiag.txt"]) Works fine thought

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently, I don't even need subprocess in fact as this:

```
os.popen(r'dxdiag /t dxdiag.txt')
```

Should work. But still does someone could tell me why the subprocess command didn't work please ? Thanks !